# How do I show a 'loading' animation while using .load in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uri

I am pulling a WSGI URI that has some details required, but there's a couple seconds of waiting time while it loads up the URI details. What's the best method of loading a animated 'loading' image until the URI response is received?

The JS code I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$('#overview').load('<WSGI URI HERE>');
});
</script>
```

Then is called in a DIV:

```
<div id="overview"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a loading indicator and hide the one when the image will be loaded. You have to add a `<div>`-block that contains the indicator and to position it on top of your image.

```
$('#overview').load('<WSGI URI HERE>', function() {
  $('#spinner').fadeOut();
});
```

Lots of loading indicators you can find at: http://preloaders.net/ru
Also you can find interesting spinners at: https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit 
and at: https://github.com/lukehaas/css-loaders

Comment: Even though I don't get the animation (might be that the URI loads before the animation), it does preload a 'loading' image, and does the job. Thanks Sasha.